# How to calculate velocity vector from gps ned

Tags: navigation, gps, coordinates, velocity

I'm getting NED velocities from gps receiver which is well accurate and I'm getting magnetic heading from a magnetometer.
So NED velocites is in x,y and z direction but how do I calcuate forward velocites form north, east velocity and magnetic heading?

Is my below approch is correct

```
x = velocity_e * sin(rad_heading)
y = velocity_n * cos(rad_heading)
forward_velocity = sqrt(x^2 + y^2)
```